# hg commands in powershell hook from tortoisehg

Tags: powershell, mercurial, tortoisehg, mercurial-hook

I created a powershell script to run as a commit hook to write the username to a file.  The command I am using in powershell to extract the username is:

```
$repodir = "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\testRepo"
cd $repodir
$hguser = hg --cwd $repodir tip | grep user
```

where $repodir is the directory of the repository.  When I commit from the powershell command line the hook executes an extracts the username as desired.  When I commit from within tortoisehg workbench the hook executes (I can see changes in my output file) but there is no information in $hguser, other hg commands also have no affect.  Is there special syntax needed to execute hg from within tortoisehg, is it executing in the correct path?

Comment: Where is `$repodir` set?

Comment: I edited the original question to show where it is set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to work for me.

**.hg/hgrc**

```
[hooks]
commit = powershell.exe -File "C:\users\andy\desktop\test\test.ps1"
```

**test.ps1**

```
$repodir = "C:\Users\andy\Desktop\Test"
cd $repodir
$hguser = (hg tip) | ? {$_ -match '^user:\s+([\w\s]+\w)'} | % {$matches[1]}
$hguser | Out-File user.txt -Encoding ASCII
```

user.txt is populated via TortoiseHg/hg.exe commit. Using TortoiseHg 2.7.

Comment: That worked.  I'll look into why it was working from within powershell but not tortoisehg.  Thanks!

Comment: Is grep a powershell alias or is it an external program? It's not a built in alias, so if it's a custom alias is might mean your powershell profile doesn't load through TortoiseHg, or if it's an external program it might mean it's not in the path in TortoiseHg.

Comment: Yes, that is it, the profile that TortoiseHg loads does not have grep.  I expected it to have a bad exit value if it called a missing function.